# I get a 400 - bad request when I published my application on 'IIS', but before publishing it worked perfectly

Tags: c#, angular, post, asp.net-core, get

I have a angular application which works fine locally, but when published it on a test server it doesn't work any more some of my POST requests returns a 400 - bad request, and some don't, I have no idea why this is working locally but once published it doesn't.

What I have tried:

►I am sure the test server has access to the database I'm connecting to since, previous versions of the application worked on it and other as well that uses the same database.

►I logged all my objects that I'm sending to the API to check if there is something missing or wrong data going through but it all looks the same locally and when published.

►I'm definitely sure this is not a cors error as I'm not getting any of those types of errors.

MY web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\pamcportal.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

One of the POST that I,m making (typscript side)

```
 GetListOfPaidBatches() {
    console.log("get paid batches: ", this.amounts);
    this.showList = true;
    this.showBordRowComponents = false;
    this._paidBatches = [];
    this._http.post(this._baseUrl + 'api/CheckRun/GetPaidBatches',
      this.amounts
    ).subscribe((recievedList: CheckRunTypeModel[]) => {
      let v = recievedList;
      this._paidBatchesType = v;
      this._paidBatchesType.forEach((pb) => {
        let key2: string = pb.batchNo.substr(0, 6);
        let contains: boolean = this._filteredPaidList.some(y => y.yearMont === key2);
        if (contains) {
          this._filteredPaidList.forEach((fl) => {
            if (fl.yearMont === key2) {
              let include = fl.list.some(y => y === pb);
              if (include === false) {
                fl.list.push(pb);
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          let d: CheckRunTypeModel[] = [];
          d.push(pb);
          this._filteredPaidList.push({
            yearMont: key2,
            list: d
          });
        }
      });
      this._paid = {};
      this._filteredPaidList.forEach((flp) => {
        let batchNumbers = flp.list;
        let indexer = flp.yearMont;
        this._paid[indexer] = batchNumbers

      });
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {

        this.showBordRowComponents = true;
        this.CheckCheckRunTypeArrayPaid(this._paidBatchesType);
        this.GetUnreleasedBatches()
      });
  }
```

and the method its calling in the API

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetPaidBatches")]
        public List<CheckRunTypeModel> GetPaidBatches([FromBody] ClaimsModel data)
        {
            CheckRunTypeModel detailedBatch = new CheckRunTypeModel();
            DataTable datatbl = new DataTable();
            List<CheckRunTypeModel> returnList = new List<CheckRunTypeModel>();
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            List<string> paidList = new List<string>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            string claimNo = "";
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            cn.ConnectionString = _portalConnection;
            if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cn.Open();
            }
            string batchNo = "";
            string clientName = "";
            string description = "";
            string hpcode = "";
            try
            {

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                        var msg = e.Message;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                var msg = e.Message;
            }


            return returnList;
        }
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working when I publish the application on 'IIS' but locally it works.

Comment: what `this._baseUrl` you are getting after publishing

Comment: Where is this being published? e.g. Is it a shared environment?

Comment: @Gopesh Sharma -- im getting the address of where application is running on (port) when published

Comment: @Kirk Larkin -- yes it is a shared environment, it a test server we use when publishing our applications.

Comment: Have you tested your api methods by postman to make sure their that their address is correct ?

Comment: @sajadre -- i did but i get the same error 400 - bad request, but something i noticed is that the calls that is not working is all making request to the same database and the ones that is working is to a different database, i don't know if this can help in any  way....

Comment: @A. vd Walt -- can you write  'this._baseUrl' value in your local and publish in here? I think that might be related to this